# Open a popup window with Javascript and attach elements from parent window

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, popup, append

I have an HTML page generated with ASP.NET, **parent.aspx**, and I would like, upon clicking on a hyperlink, to open a popup window that contains an already existing html page, **article.html** and append elements from parent.aspx to the html page . The two files, **parent.aspx** and **article.html** are in the same folder.

The **article.html**, besides containing standard elements such as header and body, inside the body has just a div without neither content nor nodes, used as placeholder for the content to append

**parent.aspx**

```
<a href="javascript:displayPopup('article.html');">Open Article</a>
<div id="articleContent">
    <table>
    <!--article content-->
    </table>
</div>
```

**article.html**

```
<body>
<div id="article"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function displayPopup(url) {
            var popupWindow;
            var width = 960;
            var height = 700;
            var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth / 2) - (width / 2));
            var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight / 2) - (height / 2));
            var articleContent = document.getElementById("articleContent").innerHTML;
            var windowProperties = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",status,resizable,left=" + left +           ",top=" + top + ",screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top + ",scrollbars=yes";
            popupWindow = window.open(url, 'article', windowProperties);
            var articleDiv = popupWindow.document.getElementById("article");
            articleDiv.innerHTML += articleContent;
            popupWindow.document.close();
            if (window.focus) 
            { popupWindow.focus() }
        }
```

I put the code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy2WG/), although I cannot insert two different HTML pages, there is just the markup for the **parent.aspx**. The code works in debug mode but for some reason it does not during normal execution. I cannot spot the error, anybody can help, please? Thanks!

UPDATE: If I inspect the code of the popup window inside the body I have

```
<body>
<div id="article" class="content"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pc-gizmos-ssl.com:9899/scripts/main.js?ver=1.0.0.6">
<form id="GM_form" target="_blank"></form>
</body>
```

I do not know where the pc-gizmos script is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the parent.aspx page, change the code to look like this:

```
<div id="articleContent">
    <b>
      This is some article content
    </b>
</div>
```

Once you've done that, try clicking on the pop-up again and you should then see "This is some article content" in bold.

Also, you never stated whether there was an error being displayed or just a blank page once you clicked on the "pop-up" link. This makes it difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: Instead of appending to the article div, try replacing everything in the div. In other words, instead of using `articleDiv.innerHTML += articleContent;` try `articleDiv.innerHTML = articleContent;` Does the script contain the pc-gizmos now?

Comment: I had an analisys with Bugzilla and it says me that 'articleDiv' is NULL